# Page Doesn't exist error for lightning page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created a lightning web component and added this on the detail page of the account as quick action. As I need to open new page with that lwc component on click on that quick action so I created a lightning page through lightning app builder and added created lwc component there.
In the lwc component I am simply fetching data from one custom object and showing that. When I login with one of the salesforce profile then it's showing error Page doesn't exist.
[image: error screenshot]

I have debugged and found that the lightning page's tab's visibility is hidden and it's not showing through quick action. If I change visibility to default off then it's started working.
Can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks